# android studio save string shared preference, start activity and load the saved string

Tags: android

I'm trying to save a string to shared preferences and then start an activity and retrieve it but doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

First I set the shared preference key then I start the activity:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor =
                                getSharedPreferences("PaymentStatus",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("payment_status","success");
editor.apply();
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

and on the ProfileActivity class I trying to retrieve the key:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PaymentStatus",
                MODE_PRIVATE);
String payment_status = prefs.getString("payment_status", null);

if(payment_status == "success"){
    Log.i("payment status", "success");
}
```

I can't see the payment status success in the logcat.

Comment: Try used without null:  prefs.getString("payment_status", "");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the code you have given is not with how you done it with shared preferences (you did that correctly btw)
Your issue is that you are comparing strings via == as this compares the string reference and not the string value. Use .equals() or .contains() instead.

```
if (payment_status.equals("success")) {
    Log.i("payment status", "success");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my experience in used SharedPreferens.
Perhaps this approach will solve the problem:

```
public class UserData {

    UserData(MainActivity mainActivity){this.mainActivity = mainActivity;}

    private static UserData userData;

    private final MainActivity mainActivity;
    private SharedPreferences sPref;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    final private String USER_ID = "user_id";

    public static void create(MainActivity activity) {
        if (userData == null) userData = new UserData(activity);
    }

    public static UserData getUserData() {
        return userData;
    }

    void createUser() {
        sPref = mainActivity.getSharedPreferences("UserData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sPref.edit();
            // Если user id уже есть, выходим из метода
        if(sPref.contains(USER_ID)) return;
        editor.putString(USER_ID, createUserId());
        editor.apply();
        Toast.makeText(mainActivity,"UserId created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
        // id формируется на основе текущей даты и времени
    private String createUserId() {
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss", Locale.getDefault());
        return dateFormat.format(currentDate);
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return sPref.getString(USER_ID, "");
    }
}
```